# Load balancing a Windows 2012 VM with internal clients

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-virtual-machine

I have a setup of two VM (win 2012) setup into one cloud service. Each VM runs a simple TCP Service that accepts connections and keeps them connected for as long as the client wishes.

The problem is that I can't connect to the endpoint twice from the same client (different TcpClient objects of course).

This is possible when not running load balanced.

There is also an issue when the server tries to connect to itself (due to some lazy coding). First time, it's ok. Second connection it failes with a "server did not respond" message.

My question is simply: Is it possible to connect from the same host more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want, you can set up specific ports on each individual virtual machine (basically endpoints that forward traffic to a specific vm). Michael Washam illustrates this in his post [here](http://michaelwasham.com/2012/06/08/understanding-windows-azure-virtual-machines/). You'd create endpoints, but not load-balanced endpoints. Your client application would then need to choose which server to connect to (based on port number). Maybe a random selection?

If, instead, you're looking for a "sticky server" solution where the client connects to a single port, gets load-balanced to one of the VM's, and then stays on that VM: you'd need to use something like haproxy, nginx, etc. running in its own VM, forwarding traffic to individual vm's based on rules you set up.

Comment: This would work but it does not answer the question if there is a known fact that you cannot connect twice? It works well as it does except that one network adapter cannot have two connections to the same endpoint. If you have 30 different people on different machines, each of these can connect once and they get load balanced correctly. That works today.

Comment: It seems my question was faulty to start with. Your answer does however solve my problem and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is valid and for the benefit of anyone else finding it:

You can't connect to the same server because the Azure Software Load Balancer uses a round-robin algorithm. So there is no guarantee which server each request will connect to.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/how-to-load-balance-virtual-machines/

"Windows Azure provides round-robin load balancing of network traffic to publicly defined ports of a cloud service"

That's why the individual port method in the other answer is the only way to force communication with a specific server.